# How to execute a webpack chunked file on a non-browser client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-5

I am using Webpack's dynamic import syntax to create chunks for a React component library. The entry file of the main bundle exports an object with a mapping for each dynamically imported component.

```
export const components = {
 getComponent1: () => import('../path/to/component1'),
 getComponent2: () => import('../path/to/component2'),
...
};
```

I am executing this bundle file on a node js application during SSR and now if I do `await getComponent1()`, it never resolves.

How can I dynamically extract the chunk details from webpack main bundle file so that I can manually load the chunk on the server?

I am using Webpack v5

NOTE: I have tried to name webpack chunks based on the object keys to maintain a manual map.

```
export const components = {
 getComponent1: () => import(/* webpackChunkName:"getComponent1" */ '../path/to/component1'),
 getComponent2: () => import(/* webpackChunkName:"getComponent2" */ '../path/to/component2'),
...
};
```

Is there any other way I can do it?